# Auto-Start Stop Question On 2017 Ford Escape

Tags: ford, transmission, escape, start-stop

I have been having tranny issues on my 2017 Ford Escape.  Got the transmission replaced got the vehicle back today and now the auto-start stop light is on the dash but it has a white line through it and the auto-start stop will never engage

I am driving it so lift gate is closed, hood is closed and all doors are closed, so I am mindblower as to why the auto-start stop feature will not engage.

Is it an underlying issue with the transmission that is not presenting?  (and was missed by dealership)

Answer (score 1):

stop/start will automatically shut down if the battery tests lower than spec. Get your battery tested.